# Get a checkout custom field value in a WooCommerce subscriptions order

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, checkout, woocommerce-subscriptions

Why can't I retrieve the data from a Woocommerce checkout field to update subscription data as the order processes?

I want to update the next renewal date based on the customers' frequency request on checkout. Here is my code:

1) Set up the checkout field:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_order_notes', 'hgf_custom_checkout_field' );

function hgf_custom_checkout_field( $checkout ) {
global $woocommerce;

    woocommerce_form_field( 'frequency', array(
        'type'          => 'select',
        'required'          => true,
        'class'         => array('form-row-wide'),
        'label'         => __('Change this any time, just email.'),
        'options'     => array(
            'blank'     => __( 'Select frequency preference', 'woocommerce' ),              
            1 => __( 'Every Week', 'woocommerce' ),
            2 => __( 'Every Other Week' , 'woocommerce' ),
            3 => __( 'Once Per Month' , 'woocommerce' )
                )
            ), $checkout->get_value( 'frequency' ));
            echo '</div>';
}
```

2) Update the order meta. This creates two custom fields on the customer order, as well as updates the billing interval on the subscription:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_update_order_meta', 'hgf_checkout_field_update_order_meta' );
function hgf_checkout_field_update_order_meta( $order_id ) {

    if ( ! empty( $_POST['frequency'] ) ) {

        update_post_meta( $order_id, 'frequency', $_POST['frequency'] );
        update_post_meta( $order_id, 'billing_interval', $_POST['frequency'] );
    }

}
```

3) Update the renewal date
For the last part, I can update the renewal date with a dummy date of my choosing (for instance: `$renewal date = "2018-12-15"`, but when I try to get it to read the `'billing_interval'` field, it reverts to the `else` default.

```
    add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_create_subscription', 'hgf_next_renewal' );
    function hgf_next_renewal( $subscription, $timezone='site' ) {

        $billing_interval = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'billing_interval', true); 

    if( $billing_interval == 2 ) {
        $renewal_date = date( 'Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime( "2017-10-01" ) ) /* date( 'Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime( "+2 weeks" ) ) */ ;
    } if( $billing_interval == 4 ) {
        $renewal_date = date( 'Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime( "2017-12-01" ) ) /* date( 'Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime( "+4 weeks" ) ) */ ;
    } else {
        $renewal_date = date( 'Y-m-d H:i:s' ) ) /* date( 'Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime( $renewal_date) ) */ ;
    }

        $subscription->update_dates( array(
            'next_payment' => $renewal_date,
            ) );

        return $subscription;
    }
```

This is all the different ways I have tried:

```
1) $billing_interval = $subscription->get_billing_interval();
2) $billing_interval = get_post_meta( $subscription->get_ID(), 'billing_interval', true);
3) $billing_interval = get_post_meta( $order_id, 'billing_interval', true);
4) $subscriptions = wcs_get_users_subscriptions( $user_id );
     foreach ( $subscriptions as $sub ) {
      $billing_interval = get_post_meta( $sub->get_order_number(), '_billing_interval', true);
      }
5) $billing_interval = $checkout->get_value( 'frequency' );
```

Does anyone know why I can't retrieve a value from my checkout field while in the `'woocommerce_checkout_create_subscription'` action?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you are saving your **`'billing_interval'`** custom field in the Order meta data, you can't get this custom field through the subscription object or ID… You need to get first **the Parent Order ID**.

> **To get the parent Order ID** from the **subscription object** you need to use the [**`WC_Order`** method **`get_parent_id()`**](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/class-WC_Abstract_Order.html#_get_parent_id)

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_create_subscription', 'hgf_next_renewal' );
function hgf_next_renewal( $subscription, $timezone='site' ) {
    
    // MISSING!: The parent order ID to set below
    $order_parent_id = $subscription->get_parent_id();
    
    $billing_interval = get_post_meta( $order_parent_id, 'billing_interval', true);

    if( $billing_interval == 2 ) {
        $renewal_date = date( 'Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime( "2017-10-01" ) ) /* date( 'Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime( "+2 weeks" ) ) */ ;
    } elseif( $billing_interval == 4 ) {
        $renewal_date = date( 'Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime( "2017-12-01" ) ) /* date( 'Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime( "+4 weeks" ) ) */ ;
    } else {
        $renewal_date = date( 'Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime( "2017-09-01" ) ) /* date( 'Y-m-d H:i:s' ) */ ;
    }

    $subscription->update_dates( array(
        'next_payment' => $renewal_date,
    ) );

    return $subscription;
}
```

*Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or theme) or also in any plugin file.*

I haven't tested your code for real, but it doesn't throw any error and should work for you this time.

Comment: THANK YOU!! I was getting nowhere with this for hours (days?), and your suggestion solved it. THANK YOU!!!

Comment: @aleks1217 This one is just very fine … Thanks :)